# How do I get the results of an SQL query?

Tags: delphi, dataset, iteration, delphi-2010

Using Delphi 2010, I have used TSQLQuery and TSQLConnection to connect to a remote MySQL server. I have used an SQL query as follows:

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email="'+email+'" and login_pass="'+password+'"';

SQLQuery1.Open; // Open sql connection
```

What should I do to list or display the data selected by this query?

When I type

```
SQLQuery1['who']; // The resault is : James Kan
```

I think it is displaying the very last item in the list. But I want to display each item, as I could with the foreach loop in PHP. How could I create, for example, a TLabel for each item?

Comment: As an aside note, the way you code SQL is the usual way to allow for "SQL Injection". Do it for a login table, and a smart user can read the whole table. You should use "SQL parameters", i.e. where email = :email and login_pass = :password.
Concatenating string without first "sanitizing" them is dangerous because a user can enter the "proper" charaters and change your query meaning wholly.

Comment: Using parameters will escape the values, but you'll want to filter out `NULL`. Also, filter out `%` and `_` with LIKE clauses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just iterate over the resultset like

```
SQLQuery1.Open;
SQLQuery1.First; // move to the first record
while(not SQLQuery1.EOF)do begin
   // do something with the current record
   ...
   // move to the next record
   SQLQuery1.Next;
end;
```

Comment: +1, you were faster. I wanted to create also the labels for each row :)

Comment: and if the query is already active and on the last record, navigate to the `First` record before looping.

Comment: If you find that your application freezes, you forgot the `Next`, which is an easy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TDBGrid to display the results quite neatly. You need a datasource which links to your query via the DataSet property of the datasource. Then the DBGrid links to the dataSource via the DataSource Property of the DBGrid.